# CSS Object Resolution

Tags: css, class, object

If two classes in CSS have the same derived class how does CSS resolve the proper class?

For example:

```
.ClassA.Left {}
.ClassB.Left {}
.Left {}
```

Since the class 'Left' can be applied to any object how can I be assured it is the one I want?
What priority is used to bind 'Left'?

Comment: Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything with `.Left` as a class will get the styles applied in `.Left`, unless it *also* has `ClassA` (`class="Left ClassA"`) then it will get the styles from `.Left` and `.ClassA.Left`, with `ClassA.Left` taking priority since it has higher specificity.  Same rules apply to `class="Left ClassB"`.

See here about specificity:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

> ## Specificity
>
> ### The concept
>
> Specificity is the means by which a browser decides which property
>   values are the most relevant to an element and gets to be applied.
>   Specificity is only based on the matching rules which are composed of
>   selectors of different sorts.
>
> ### How is it calculated?
>
> The specificity is calculated on the concatenation of the count of
>   each selectors type. It is not a weight that is applied to the
>   corresponding matching expression.
>
> In case of specificity equality, the latest declaration found in the
>   CSS is applied to the element.
>
> Note: Proximity of elements in the document tree has no effect on the
>   specificity.
>
> #### Crescent order of specificity
>
> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal selectors
> - Type selectors
> - Class selectors
> - Attributes selectors
> - Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - Inline style
>
> ### The !important exception
>
> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.
>
> ### The :not exception
>
> The negation pseudo-class :not is not considered as a pseudo-class in
>   the specificity calculation. Although, selectors placed into the
>   negation pseudo-class count as normal selectors.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Equally, if the element had all three classes (ClassA, ClassB and Left) the the order in which the classes are listed in your CSS sheet matters.

.ClassA.Left would be beaten by .ClassB.Left (for common properties) as .ClassB.Left was lower in the cascade.

Single class selectors are beaten by multiple class selectors, thus .ClassA.Left beats .ClassA

Source order of the classes in the HTML is not a factor.

**[Codepen Specificity Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Lbesf)**